# Print the contents of the file

Tags: c

I am trying to print the contents of my file byte by byte. However, I do get the compiler error "invalid type argument of unary *(have int)

my code is :

```
 void print_the_file ()
    {
       void *file_hndl;
       UINT32 file_size = 2048;
       UINT8 *hndl; 
       file_hndl = fopen("my_bin_file.bin", "r") ;
       if ( file_hndl == NULL )
       {
          printf("file open failed");
       }
       hndl = (UINT8*)file_hndl;
     /* print the contents */
      for ( UINT32 i = 0; i< 2048; i++ )
    {
        printf ("%02x", *hndl[i] );
    }
   }
```

Please advise me where i am going wrong and right way to print the contents of the file.

Comment: On what line do you get that error? We need the actual code that you're compiling (see [mcve]) and the exact error you're getting - we have nowhere near enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Replace `*hndl[i]` with `hndl[i]`.

Comment: I am getting error on line "printf ("%02x", *hndl[i] );

Comment: I tried replacing *hndl[i] with hndl[i] and it prints the garbage values

Comment: Well, you never actually read anything from the file. You just dump the contents of a `FILE` object and any junk memory after it up to a total of 2048 bytes. Hint: A `FILE` object does not contain the contents of the file. It is just a control structure.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` returns a `FILE *` so your `file_hndl` should be of that type. Whilst you're checking the return value from `fopen` to print out an error message, you then ignore it and continue on trying to read from the file.

You're not actually reading from the file though - you need to call other functions such as `fgetc` to do that. But using `fopen`/`fgetc` is probably not want you want anyway as you're trying to read in a binary file. For that you want to use `open` and `read`.

The code below does what you're actually trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void print_the_file(void)
    {
    int file_desc;
    char a_byte;
    size_t err;

    file_desc=open("my_bin_file.bin",O_RDONLY,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    if(file_desc==-1)
        {
        printf("file open failed\n");
        return;
        }
    do
        {
        err=read(file_desc,&a_byte,1);
        if(err>0)
            {
            printf("%02x",a_byte);
            }
        }
    while(err>0);
    }
```

Comment: But why the switch from standard C functions to low-level POSIX functions?

Comment: @IanAbbott Because screw portability. I have seen production code written like this.

Comment: @IanAbbott `fopen` doesn't have a reliable way to open a binary file - the 'b' flag isn't very widely supported according to the manpage.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Which version of the manpage? The 'b' flag has been standard since the original ANSI standardization.

Comment: @IanAbbott Not sure where to find the version, but the latest version still says the same thing I'm reading http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html

Comment: @ChrisTurner It says "adding the 'b' may be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that your program may be ported to non-UNIX environments". It doesn't say it isn't widely supported.

Comment: @IanAbbott but it also says "the  'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux."

Comment: @ChrisTurner That's because there is no difference between text and binary I/O streams on POSIX conforming systems.

Answer (score 0):

the error was fired because of * in front of the variable hndl

```
for ( UINT32 i = 0; i< 2048; i++ )
    {
       // printf ("%02x", *hndl[i] );
       printf ("%02x", fgetc(hndl) );
       // remove * if you are using [] or write like this *(hndl+i)
    }
```

make sure that you are compiling it with C99 or higher standard. for this

```
for ( UINT32 i = 0; i< 2048; i++ )
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the above code print the contents of the file or just dump the contents of file object

Comment: it will print 2048 bytes from the file

Comment: @crook Actually, no it won't because `hndl` is just pointing to the `FILE` object.

Comment: hell yeah it's just memory dump lmao. didn't notice from where data is coming lol.. my bad

Comment: Now it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
void print_the_file()
{
    FILE* file_hndl = fopen("my_bin_file.bin", "rb");
    if (file_hndl == NULL)
    {
        printf("file open failed");
    }
    else
    {
        while (!feof(file_hndl) && !ferror(file_hndl))
        {
            int c = fgetc(file_hndl);
            if (c != EOF) /* should be redundant */
            {
                printf("%02x", c);
            }
        }
        fclose(file_hndl);
    }
}
```

Note the file mode to `fopen` is `"rb"` to open the file for read as binary.

Also, the routine processes the entire file character by character until EOF or error occurs.